# Set value of a cell of the FlowDocument Table

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to insert

```
  var f = new Floater
                            {
                                Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0),
                                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                                Width = 210
                            };
```

into the table cell

```
var table = myFlowDocument.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Table;

table.RowGroups[0].Rows[0].Cells[0].SetValue(???);
```

And really cannot figure our how to do it.

Also it is unclear how to clean the cell.

Any clue?

Thank you!

(This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.aspx) and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753342.aspx) about are not helping...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablecell.blocks.aspx) property on MSDN :

```
var cell = table.RowGroups[0].Rows[0].Cells[0];

// Clear the content
cell.Blocks.Clear();

// Add some text
cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Hello world")));

// Add a floater
cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Floater()));
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to directly edit a cell, paragraph or run value?